# How to create equal height pricing tables with buttons at the bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've designed some pricing tables on my site and got them to be responsive "horizontally", but not "vertically". My goal is to make all the three pricing tables be equal in height, and have the "Subscribe" buttons stick to the bottom, and so that whenever the content is added to the body of one pricing table, all the other pricing tables will inherit the height of the longest table, up until a certain breakpoint.

Kind of how like [this site](https://weboth.us/preview/fluxo-v1.0.0/html/pricing.html#0) has it. They have a similar idea, which I've been trying to implement into my own, using flexbox and `margin-top: auto;` for the footer of the pricing table so the buttons stay at the bottom, however nothing I've tried seems to be working. I understand the concept behind it, but my implementation is wrong. As you can see in the screenshot below, the heights of my pricing table all vary based on how much content is in the body of one particular div and it looks pretty untidy. The middle (popular) pricing table is scaled up by 1.1. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am new to CSS flexbox. I have also searched on Stack Overflow for similar questions, and while people have had similar questions answered, the solutions didn't work for me.

[image]

Comment: Add a custom class to the row containing the pricing table, e.g. `equal-pricing-btns` and then add the following rules to either the page or Custom CSS: `.et_pb_pricing_table_wrap {align-items: normal;}` and `.equal-pricing-btns .et_pb_pricing {min-height: 235px !important;}`

Answer (score 1):

Add this css

```
ul.cd-pricing-list{
  display: flex;
}
ul.cd-pricing-list  li ul{
  height:100%;
}
ul.cd-pricing-list  li ul li{
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in solving the equal height issue! But, the buttons still don't stick to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.PriceTableAll{
display: flex;

}
.pricetable {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 200px;
margin: 0 20px;
border: 1px solid #000;
text-align: center;
}
.pricetable a {
margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="PriceTableAll">
<div class="pricetable">
<h2>Standard</h2>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<a href"#">Button</a>
</div>
<div class="pricetable">
<h2>Standard</h2>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<a href"#">Button</a>
</div>

</div>
```

I used "margin-top: auto" for button for equal height.